# Meteor CSS style disappears AFTER page is rendered

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

Has anyone experienced Meteor JS web app first loads correctly with the correct CSS styling (compiled using the [fourseven:scss](https://atmospherejs.com/fourseven/scss) package) but would then lose the styling in a few seconds.

It seems once the page is ready (2-3 seconds later) with all the subscription ready the CSS would actually disappear. **It would literally disappear from the Chrome Sources profile**. The link to the CSS is still accessible, just no longer a part of the web app. It also works fine locally and on dev just have the above trouble on production server

We are also MaterializeCSS, Iron Router, Accounts plus some other packages on Modulus... I could show the whole list if it helps?

Thanks all

Comment: So does all CSS get removed? Because I thought Meteor merges and minifies all CSS files.

Comment: Not all, the materializecss.com css are all still there. Just all the custom ones we have written which is compiled as a separate css file. Thx

Comment: We ended up starting a new modulus server which seems to have solved the problem. Not a good solution, but it worked